# Typescript inferred type cannot be named without reference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup, tsdx

My project's setup is `tsdx` (based on `Rollup` and `Typescript`).
Working in my IDE (vscode) everything looks fine, and even running `yarn tsc` works without errors.

When I'm running `yarn build` (which is `tsdx build`) I get the following error:

```
(typescript) Error: /home/me/dev/app/src/components/alert/Alert.tsx(36,7): semantic error TS2742: The inferred type of 'AlertContainer' cannot be named without a reference to '@emotion/serialize/node_modules/csstype'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
Error: /home/me/dev/app/src/components/alert/Alert.tsx(36,7): semantic error TS2742: The inferred type of 'AlertContainer' cannot be named without a reference to '@emotion/serialize/node_modules/csstype'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

The code referenced in the error is:

```js
type AlertContainerProps = {
  theme: any
};
const AlertContainer = styled(animated.div)<AlertContainerProps>`
  ${(props) => props.theme.primaryView}
  ...
`;

...

type AlertContentProps = Pick<React.ComponentProps<typeof AlertContainer>, 'style'> & {
  status?: string
};
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
I tried [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42873#issuecomment-1007540868) solution but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solutions about this ?

Comment: No, I have just types it as any

Answer (score 6):

This helped me

```
import { StyledComponent } from '@emotion/styled';
import type { BoxProps } from '@mui/material/Box';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const BoxStyled: StyledComponent<BoxProps> = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({ .......
```

Answer (score 1):

When running the script "build" in monorepo NestJS and NextJS I got this error:

```
Type error: The inferred type of 'trpc' cannot be named without a reference to '../../server/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

Client side:

```
import { AppRouter } from '@server/trpc/trpc.router';

export const trpc =
  createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({
    links: [
      //TODO: use env variable
      httpBatchLink({ url: `http://localhost:5000/trpc` }),
    ],
  });
```

Server side:

```
...
export type AppRouter = TrpcRouter['appRouter'];
```

Apparently the client-side error was caused by Typescript trying to import AppRouter as a function rather than as a type.

Adding the settings to the root tsconfig.json file helped solve the problem:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  }
}
```

The solution to the problem is taken from here:
https://lightrun.com/solutions/microsoft-typescript-the-inferred-type-of-x-cannot-be-named-without-a-reference-to-y-this-is-likely-not-portable-a/

Comment: Thanks this solved it for me. It seemed like I couldn't possibly get the type from elsewhere to annotate my export.

Comment: Hmm maybe not. It also generated about 100 new errors on my project...

Answer (score 0):

In case you are the one who created the npm package

### Possible problem reason

I had this issue because I created an npm package and didnt export some internal types. typescript couldnt infer the types because it had no access to it.

### Solutions

- 1st solution, Modify the function signature to use exported types only, so it doesnt rely on type infering.
- 2nd solution, If you want to rely on infer then modify the npm package to export the internal types

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you are exporting a function whose return type could not be inferred by TypeScript

For example, consider the code snippet

```js
const foo = async () => {
  const data = someExternalLibary.doStuff();
  return data;
};
```

If TypeScript throws the following error:-

```
The inferred type of `foo` cannot be named without a reference to `../node_modules/someExternalLibary`. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

this means that TS is saying that `someExternalLibary.doStuff()`'s return type could not be inferred because the return type of `doStuff` is not exported by `someExternalLibrary` library

---

So what's solution? just add the type annotation to `data`. Say, required type annotated is `DoStuffReturnType`

```js
const foo = async () => {
  const data: DoStuffReturnType = someExternalLibary.doStuff(); // Add type annotation to `data`
  return data;
};
```

Now you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript needs a reference for that type so put this at the top of the file that is causing the error:

```
/// <reference types="@emotion" />
```